# Javascript Global Format Currency

Tags: javascript

I have been searching for hours and there appears to be no simple way to present a number in local currency. I have gotten very close but I can't get the last piece of info, being the local currency code ('USD' for United States in the below example)

using navigator.language I can get the local format ('en-US', etc), which is great. one step closer to a perfect global currency formatter, but still cannot get the currency code!

```
const formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat(navigator.language, {
  style: 'currency',
  currency: 'USD',
  minimumFractionDigits: 0
});
```

I have found web sites that have large tables with every currency code for each country. I could try importing all that data into a table and then mapping a gps location or browser location to one of those but that is going to be messy. Other option is to let the user selected from a drop-down, but again that is very messy.

Are we really in the year 2020 and no one has thought to create a dynamic way to get the local currency code to the browser?

Has anyone solved this?

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I came up with. Possibly the world's first global currency formatter. Should work perfectly in any country. (requires jQuery):

```
function formatNumberToLocalCurrency(amount=0, refresh=false) {
  if (refresh || !localStorage.geoplugin_currencyCode) {
    $.getJSON('http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?jsoncallback=?', function (data) {
      localStorage.geoplugin_currencyCode = data.geoplugin_currencyCode;
    });
  }

  const formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat(navigator.language || 'en-US', {
    style: 'currency',
    currency: localStorage.geoplugin_currencyCode || 'USD',
    minimumFractionDigits: 0
  });
  return formatter.format(amount);
}
```